Querying Subgraphs and Creating Virtual Relationships based on nodes not available in the sub-graph
I have two different graphs where there are different types of nodes. I am working with specific nodes that are :

FEATURE
THREAT
GAP
FACT

Both types of nodes are there in the main and sub-graph. Sub-graph is a part of main graph that is generated after performing some operations on different nodes through an application.
The sub-graph does not have some gap nodes that are there in the main graph. I am able to query this through the cypher I wrote.
The FACT nodes that are there in the main-graph have the keys like this:
f_console_login_S3S whereas the FACT nodes in the sub-graph have keys like this: f_console_login_S3S#347585d0-e092-4808-a492-7b7a38e04dcd. A session-id is added at the end of the main-graph key separated by # symbol.
Here is what I am trying to do:

Query both main and sub-graph and find the gaps that are not there in the sub-graph.
Generate a graph with virtual relations based on these gaps from main/sub-graph.
The FACT nodes in sub-graph have an additional property called answer that is not there in the main graph.
In my query, it generates the graph having all the nodes from the main-graph including the FACT nodes which is as expected as the GAPs fetched are not there in the sub-graph.
I want to get the FACT nodes from the sub-graph to include in the final graph as I do not want to alter the main-graph nodes to add the answer property.

What my query does is that it takes everything from main graph and does not let me add the FACT nodes from the sub-graph.
Here is a working query that generates the graph using main graph nodes.
// Step 1: Extract main graph nodes using apoc.path.spanningTree
MATCH (n) WHERE n.key = "Test S3 Storage"
CALL apoc.path.spanningTree(n, {maxLevel: 15}) YIELD path
WITH nodes(path) AS mainGraphNodes
UNWIND mainGraphNodes AS node
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT node.key) AS mainKeys, COLLECT(DISTINCT node) AS allMainGraphNodes

// Step 2: Extract sub-graph nodes using apoc.path.spanningTree
MATCH (n) WHERE n.key = "Test S3 Storage#347585d0-e092-4808-a492-7b7a38e04dcd"
CALL apoc.path.spanningTree(n, {maxLevel: 15}) YIELD path
WITH mainKeys, allMainGraphNodes, nodes(path) AS subGraphNodes
UNWIND subGraphNodes AS node
WITH mainKeys, allMainGraphNodes, 

     COLLECT(DISTINCT SPLIT(node.key, "#")[0]) AS subGraphKeys, 
     COLLECT(DISTINCT node) AS allSubGraphNodes

// Step 3: Identify missing nodes in the sub-graph
UNWIND mainKeys AS mainKey
WITH mainKey, subGraphKeys, allMainGraphNodes,allSubGraphNodes
WHERE NOT mainKey IN subGraphKeys
WITH COLLECT(mainKey) AS missingInSubGraph, allMainGraphNodes,allSubGraphNodes

// Step 4: Filter for GAP nodes in the main graph
UNWIND missingInSubGraph AS missingKey
UNWIND allMainGraphNodes AS node
MATCH (gap:GAP)
WHERE gap.key = node.key AND gap.key = missingKey
WITH COLLECT(gap) AS missingGAPNodes, allMainGraphNodes,allSubGraphNodes

// Step 5: Create virtual relationships
UNWIND missingGAPNodes AS g
MATCH (fe:FEATURE)-->+(t:THREAT)-[]->+(g)
MATCH (g)<--+(fa_main:FACT)

UNWIND allSubGraphNodes AS subNode
// MATCH (fa_sub:FACT)
//WHERE SPLIT(fa_sub.key, "#")[0] = fa_main.key // Match the sub-graph FACT node to the main graph FACT node

WITH fe, t, g,fa_main
WITH collect(DISTINCT [fe, t]) + collect(DISTINCT [t, g]) AS hases, collect(DISTINCT [fa_main, g]) AS requireses
WITH COLLECT { 
    WITH hases 
    UNWIND hases AS pair 
    RETURN [pair[0], apoc.create.vRelationship(pair[0], 'HAS', {}, pair[1]), pair[1]] AS tuple 
} + COLLECT { 
    WITH requireses 
    UNWIND requireses AS pair 
    RETURN [pair[0], apoc.create.vRelationship(pair[0], 'REQUIRE', {}, pair[1]), pair[1]] AS tuple 
} AS tuples
UNWIND tuples AS tuple
RETURN tuple[0], tuple[1], tuple[2]

When I add the following condition in this cypher, it start throwing an error:
MATCH (fa_sub:FACT)
WHERE SPLIT(fa_sub.key, "#")[0] = fa_main.key // Match the sub-graph FACT node to the main graph FACT node

Here is the error

Neo.DatabaseError.Statement.ExecutionFailed
Index 3 out of bounds for length 2

This part is commented out in my query that I posted in the question.
I am unable to understand why it is causing the issue as if I return subNode defined in the query in step 5, it returns all the nodes from the sub-graph. The error is not making any sense to me as there is not any additional message or logs provided.
Here is the output of the query I provided:


From the error message, it looks like your tuples do not have a third index in the list. If you just return the tuples (and don't unwind them), can you verify that every tuple list includes 3 items?

note: if you think a question needs more detail/clarity, you are discouraged from answering it until that detail/clarity is added. see [answer].
